# Laravel 4 class not found error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting an error that a class (a controller) is not being found.  Thing is, it is found in my local development environment.  I created the controller with `php artisan controller:make CssController --path=app/controllers/home`.

I renamed the class (not the file) Home_CssController.  I added the route:

```
Route::get('home/css-php', 'Home_CssController@index');
```

to my routes file.  Everything works fine in my local environment.  I did forget to run `composer dump-autoload` but there were no issues with viewing the controller/view in my local environment.  I've uploaded everything to the live server, but I'm getting the error:

```
Class Home_CssController does not exist
```

I've uploaded the controller, the routes file and the view multiple times.  But I still get the error.  Is it because the controller wasn't registered with composer?  I've since registered it, but am not sure what I need to upload to the server.  I've uploaded both the `config` and `bootstrap` folders.  What do I need to do to get the controller/view to be found?  This is Laravel 4.

Comment: You said you didn't rename the file. Did you try renaming it to see if that works?

Comment: I found the solution.  You have to upload the vendor/composer folder and the autoload.php file in the vendor directory.

Answer (score 1):

If the controller isn't in the `app/controllers` folder, then it will need to be namespaced (unless you want to continue using your autoload.php trick).

Namespace `Home_CssController` to `Home`.

```
<?php namespace Home;

class CssController extends \BaseController
```

Then, you can use it in your routes:

```
Route::get('home/css-php', 'Home\CssController@index');
```